# How track clicks on links, what does "event without interaction" influence

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

Google Analytics can show you which previous page brought your visitors to a page, but it can't tell you which button it was.

So I set up event tracking for buttons and links, to figure out later which button was clicked.

**Are these button-clicks *Events Without Interaction*?**

One example in the documentation states that if you were tracking clicks on a «Read More» button by means of events, you would set «Event without Interaction» to false, since it should create a new page view (it's opening the next page).

Other parts of the documentation only mention influences on the calculation of *bounce rate*.

For my understanding that's just wrong:

1. The Click-Event is called. This does not change anything, except for forwarding the info to Analytics
2. The browser handles the click by changing page. This will be tracked as a new page view, since the tracking code is loaded freshly.

With that understanding you'd only set *Event without Interaction* to false if your script, not your browser, handles the page load.

Or does the *Event Without Interaction* prevent the following page load from being tracked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interaction Events do influence the bounce rate.

Analytics defines a bounce as someone loading your site and then leaving with 0 interactions. Consider a visitor landing on your article page, clicks the "read more" button and then exits the browser.

If you attach a GA event to clicking the "read more" button and set it to be an `Event without interaction = true` then this would count as a bounce. If `Event without interaction = false` is set, then this user would not count as a bounce because he had an interaction on the site.

A good example where you want to use non-interaction events are "scroll depth tracking via events". That way a user coming to your site and scrolling all the way to the bottom, then leaving without a subsequent pageview it would be recorded as a bounce as GA intends it.

`Event without interaction` has no affect on subsequent pageloads or how the browser handles anything. Loading a second page would automatically make the session a non-bounce session since loading page #2 is considered an interaction with the site.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not yet sound. 'read more' would never be counted as a bounce, since the linked page will load. Maybe a rating button would be a better example?

Comment: Lots of "read more" buttons just load content via AJAX and don't actually cause another page to be loaded and therefore not a pageview. A rating button or a "share this on social media network XYX" button works just as well as an example